# ASP.NET MVC Read Raw JSON Post Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jsonfx

This is driving me crazy. I'm using ASP.NET MVC. I have a controller with an HttpPost action that acts as a callback URL that is called by another server (not under my control). I want to dynamically read JSON posted to it without using WebAPI or Model Binding. The URL also has a query string parameter passed to it.

The callback URL looks something like this:

http://domain.com/callback?secret=1234

I've tried reading the posted input using:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Callback( String secret )
{
    String jsonData = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

    // ...
}
```

However "jsonData" is always null or empty.

I just want to get the posted input and stick it into JsonFx so I can dynamically access the contents. Any ideas on how to do this the easiest possible way?

**UPDATE**

I've discovered the following ...

While the above DOES NOT work (jsonData will be null or empty), the following DOES if I configure what little options I have on the calling server so as to omit the "secret" query string parameter, which is about all I can do on that end since it is not my server. In this case, jsonData will have the correct posted JSON string:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Callback( /* String secret */ )
{
    String jsonData = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

    // ...
}
```

This is very frustrating to work around and I don't know an easy way to accept both a query string and posted JSON data on a standard MVC controller.

I have a "callback controller" with Action methods that accept various data (via GET, via form POST, via JSON POST, via JSON POST w/ a Query String, etc.) from different third-party servers. These are merchant-type callbacks where I have no control over the formats or methods used to convey information. I just need to accept the callbacks and process the information that should be there.

All of it works fine in my Controller, except the case of "JSON POST w/ a Query String".

**This appears (at least to me) to be a shortcoming in standard ASP.NET MVC controllers. ???**

Can anyone suggest a solution to this that can be used in a standard ASP.NET MVC controller?

Comment: when you post it, have all the json equal `jsonData`. e.g. `[{jsonData: [{ ... all json stuff ... }]}];` I haven't tested this, but it may work

Comment: I have no control over the server that posts the information. I added an update above.

Comment: why do you select the name 'jsonData'?, the json data could be coming on a different name, try to inspect FormCollection for the name.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Your initial approach should work if you take into consideration the fact, that ASP.NET MVC model binding has already read the stream, so you should rewind it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Callback(string secret)
{
    Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I knew there had to be a simple solution.

Comment: this does work but any ideas about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441571/get-post-request-parameters-in-custom-authorizeattribute

Answer (score 3):

Reset the `position` to `Zero` before reading the stream.
`Request.InputStream.Position = 0`

Answer (score 3):

For ASP.NET Core 2，this works for me.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RawTest() {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {  
            string content = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
```