# How to retrieve data from GWT Request Builder in C#

Tags: c#, java, asp.net-mvc, gwt

I am making a web app and part of the app is designed in ASP.NET MVC and another part in Java with GWT. I need to send a parameter from GWT in ASP.NET.Here is the code:

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, getRootUrl() + "/" + "SOME_CONTROLLER");
    return builder.sendRequest("parameter", callback);
```

My question is: How can I retrieve this string "parameter" in ASP.NET?

Comment: Can you paste everything that fiddler shows to you when you send a request from java ?

Comment: This request from java only calls controller.I want to check value of string which is sent.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `GET` method, the `data` parameter to `sendRequest` is ignored (because GET requests don't have a payload/body).

So either switch to `POST`, then you'll be posting "raw data" (note: you should set the `Content-Type` header to match what you're sending; here it looks like `text/plain`), so you'll have it in `Request.InputStream` in ASP.NET MVC.
You might have to seek back to the beginning of the stream though: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858159/116472

Or switch to a *proper* GET, passing the parameter in the URL somehow (query-string, whatever).