# How to store and update JSON data into file using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to store and update POST json data into a file using ASP.NET MVC. I'm sending data:

```
$http({
    url: "AddMenus",
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: MenusInfo,
    headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});
```

Add Menus is action method and MenusInfo is a JSON object.

Comment: ok, what's the problem?

Comment: how to store that json object into a file? @manish

Comment: You want to [get the raw JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822278/asp-net-mvc-read-raw-json-post-data) and [write the text to a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx).  Hey presto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming no other requirements other than to read the JSON from the request and update the JSON contained in that file **as requested in the question**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMenus()
{
    // Get the raw json
    Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string jsonData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

    // Creates or overwrites the file with the contents of the JSON
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\textfile.txt", jsonData);
}
```