# POST JSON from Angular frontend to ASP.NET backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I would like to send data (originally arrays) as JSONs to my MVC-controller in the backend. I was trying this:

my-ng-service.ts

```
//...
setEmployees(employees) {
    var employeesJSON = JSON.stringify(employees);
    console.log(employeesJSON); //working
    this.http.post('/api/employees', employeesJSON).subscribe();
}
//...
```

EmployeesController.cs

```
//...
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[HttpPost]
public void Post(JsonResult data)
{
    Console.Write("hallo: " + data); //error see below
}
//...
```

I don't know how I have to write my controller. Can anybody help me?

Current error:

> System.Argument.Exception: Type 'Microsoft-AspNetCore.Mvc:JsonResult'
>   does not have a default constructor Parameter name: type

Thanks in forward!

Comment: Why not just use `public JsonResult Post(string data)`? Never use `JsonResult` as action method argument because it used to return JSON data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonResult` is a type you use to *output* JSON from an action method, not as input parameter.

See [ASP.NET Core MVC : How to get raw JSON bound to a string without a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952002/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-get-raw-json-bound-to-a-string-without-a-type) and [ASP.NET MVC Read Raw JSON Post Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822278/asp-net-mvc-read-raw-json-post-data): you can change the parameter type to `dynamic` or `JObject`, or you can manually read the request body as string.

But you should really reconsider this. Creating a model so you can bind your model strongly-typed is a matter of seconds work, and will benefit you greatly in the future.

Comment: That's now working with JSON. Thanks a lot! But you're right. To use my model (already existing) that would be better. Do you want to give me a hint how I have to do this?

I created this method to get and set my MVC-modelconsisting of id and name:
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You just change the parameter type to `EmployeeViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually write the model name that you want to get from http request

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(YourJsonModel ModelObject)
    {
        Console.Write("hallo: " + data); //error see below
    }
```

Comment: But then you have to have a model.

Comment: Yeah If i dont have any model then jobject and dynamic is alright either we can grab the value from Request also